# How to free up a char*** memory properly In C so I don't get memory leak

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I got the following code

```
int rows = 123;
int cols = 12;
char ***data = (char ***)malloc(rows * sizeof(char **));
if(data) {
    for(int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++)
    {
        data[i] = (char **)malloc(cols * sizeof(char *));
        if(!data[i])
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                free(data[j]);
            free(data);
            printf("no memory\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
char randomData[] = "<Inserts random string here everytime>";
for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
     for(int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
         data[row][col] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (1 + strlen(randomData)));
         strcpy(data[row][col], randomData);
     }
}
```

This example I wrote for this stackoverflow because real code is similar but `<Inserts random string here everytime>` is output from each SQL row and each column.

I just want to make a multi-dimensional array like `data[row][column]`

How do I free it up properly when I am done?

I was thinking to clear it up I have to first clear the first star. `char *`

```
for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
     for(int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
         free(data[row][col]);
     }
}
```

Then clear up the second star `char **`

```
for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
     free(data[row]);
}
```

Then I can finally clear the last triple star `char ***`

```
    free(data);
```

Is this how you do it? seems like a overkill too much free's.. is the

```
for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
     for(int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
         free(data[row][col]);
     }
}
```

enough?

Comment: "Seems like a overkill too much free's..", well, you got so many `malloc`s! You need a single `free` statement for every single `malloc`. That includes every occurrence inside loops; so, "yes".

Comment: @Jongware does that mean I need both `free(data[row][col]);` and `free(data[row]);` I already know I need `free(data);` at the very end. Something tells me `data[row][col]` seems like it could two 2 at once. then again yeah it seems really `data[row][col]` will just clear the actual string itself, not the matrix itself. How can I tell which I must do data[row] or data[col]? because those are just numbers row/col I mean.

Comment: Absolutely. You *malloc* them, so you need to *free* them as well. It's as straightforward as it can get.

Comment: so I run like 1 malloc then 123 mallocs then who knows how much like 15129 mallocs lol.. I know i'll miss something for sure.

Comment: .. The above said, you may be thinking of `malloc (rows * cols * sizeof(char *))`. This *will* put both rows and columns in a contiguous memory chunk. If the number of rows and columns is static, you could consider that -- but you need to do the math for row/column indexing "manually".

Comment: Ahh I understand the pattern now the `[][]`'s fall off one at a time for each free in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must de-allocate everything you malloc'ed.

At most you can save a loop by writing :

```
for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
     for(int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
         free(data[row][col]);
     }
     free(data[row]);
}
free(data);
```

If you want to de-allocate in a single pass, you must allocate in a single pass, but it is tricky for an array of pointers and must be commented in a red flashing font :

```
data = malloc(rows * (1 + cols) * sizeof(void *));
for (i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    data[i] = &(data[cols * i]);
}
```

De-allocate would then be :

```
for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
     for(int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
         free(data[row][col]);
     }
}
free(data);
```

If you prefer, you can allocate directly a 2D array :

```
data = malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(void *));
```

But then, you must access to the individual elements by `data[j + i * rows]` ... to be commented in red flashing font ...

Comment: oh wow you avoided a whole loop for me too haha I guess since you a professional I'll trust your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to free as much as you malloc

To free the whole array it depends on your array dimension,

lets see first how you allocate this array :

```
1 - char ***array = char pointer to 2d arrays (A)

2 - **array= char pointer to 2d array         (B)

3 - *array= char pointer to (vector) of char  (C)
```

if you have ***array you need to start by :

```
1 - freeing each vector of your inner array (C)
2 - freeing inner array pointer             (B)                  
3 - freeing the main pointer                (A)
```

for your example you can do :

```
for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
        free(data[row][column]);
    }
    free(data[row]);
}
free(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Every single call to `malloc` needs a single call to `free`. You already outlined the correct (!) way to free up all allocations. The number of `free`s should not be a problem (after all, you have no problem with the exact same number of calls to `malloc`).

If you want to test to be sure, add some low-level debugging code:

1. Add an integer `int number_of_allocations = 0;` at the top of your routine.
2. *Increment* it after every single `malloc`.
3. *Decrement* it after each `free`.
4. Test if the net result is 0 at the end.

As far as I can tell, there should be no leak in there.

Comment: Haha yeah I know how much malloc's i do by simple math but I just don't want to free the ones I already freed.

Comment: You were doing it right: in the reverse order of allocation. No worries there.

Comment: I really appreciate your help you really made my mystery logic more solid, I would accept your answer as the best but Serge's code is what I used as of right now also optimized a loop away, I completely missed that and seems it all fits in with everything else I was really looking for. Thanks man I gave you a plus. although it does have a syntax error in it lol